# How safe is it to upgrade to a beta iOS then downgrade again?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Apple responded to one of my bug reports suggesting I try to reproduce the issue in the beta version of the next iOS. As with all betas before, this one comes with a warning that

> iOS [version] beta should only be installed on devices dedicated exclusively for iOS [version] beta testing. Do not install this software if you do not have a device dedicated exclusively for iOS [version] beta testing.

I don't have a device dedicated exclusively to beta testing. I'd like to resolve this bug, so ideally I could upgrade, try to reproduce the issue, then downgrade the device so I can continue normal development on it.

With my limited google skills, I've found some [articles](http://blog.merrycode.com/how-to-downgrade-ios-4-1-beta-to-ios-4-0-on-iphone-4-3gs/) that describe doing this with the previous iOS beta, but they tend to be poorly written and require running some third-party app ("RecBoot").

I'm not going to go through this process until I have more information. What I'd like to hear is if someone has done this in the past, or knows more about how it works, and can tell me with certainty that it's safe or dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Apple-supported way to downgrade, so I'd never want to depend on downgrading on production equipment no matter what people's past experiences have been.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you should only update to beta releases of iOS if you have a dedicated development device (as Apple recommend).  In the past, I've updated my iPhone to beta releases and lost access to Wifi, the camera and generally had an unstable environment for everyday use.

I'm pretty sure you can't downgrade once you upgrade.  I'm not an expert on this but it's something to do with the baseband being upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. Since I'm developing with private resources, buying double or triple of each handset is out of the question and even though we are registered developers, there is no official way to do this.

When trying though, iTunes gave me the 1064 error code.

I got around this problem by using the redsn0w OS X application. There's an option that "fixes" the DFU-mode so the error disappears, and iTunes restores the iPhone/piPad to a 4.3.5 again using the ipsw-file for it.

However, be aware of that this might not work for everyone and that this kind of procedure could have an impact on your product warranty.

Answer (score 0):

(A very late answer, but for future reference as my searching came across this question.)

To answer the implied 'is it possible?' part of your question:

Yes it is, I just downgraded from iOS 9 beta to 8.4 using iTunes 12.2.1.16, so the downgrade operation is supported by standard Apple software without any need for jailbreaking:

1. I obtained the relevant iOS 8.4 IPSW file for my device from Apple's download servers at appldnld.apple.com. (The [theiphonewiki.com site](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware) has a list of links for the IPSW files, or you can Google search the [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com) site for IPSW files.)
2. Open iTunes, select your device and go the Summary page. Option-click on the 'Restore iPad...' button, choose your IPSW file and follow the prompts.

To answer the 'how safe is it?' part of your question, Apple's warning on downloading the iOS 9 beta includes:

> Devices updated to iOS 9 beta can not be restored to earlier versions
>   of iOS. Only registered development devices will be able to upgrade to
>   future beta releases and the final iOS software.

So I wouldn't advise getting in a situation where you need to do this on a production device, but my experience with my development device has been problem free and this procedure has been invaluable in enabling me to switch back and forth between iOS versions as necessary.